# Burgers equation with initial condition defined with cases

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am trying to solve Burgers equation using the method of characteristics:
$$\partial_tu+u \partial_x u=0$$
with the following initial condition:
$$\begin{cases}
1 & x<0 \\
1-x & 0\leq x \leq 1 \\
0 & x>1 
\end{cases}$$
Then using the Method of characteristics I find that:
$$X(t)=u(t,X(t))t+x$$
And 
$$u(t,X(t))=u(0,x)$$
And so for example if $x\in [0,1]$ then $u(t,X(t))=1-x=1-(X(t)-u(t,X(t)) t)$

which means that $u(t,X(t))=\frac{1-X(t)}{1-t}$

The problem is that I can't find the explicit cases

Answer (score 1):

According to the equation $X(t) = u(0,x)t + x$ in OP,

- if $u(0,x)=1$, then $X = t+x$ with $x<0$, i.e. $X < t$.
- if $u(0,x)=1-x$, then $X = u(0,x)t+ x$ with $0\leq x\leq 1$. Thus, $$u = u\big(0,X - u t\big) = 1-X + u t\, ,$$
  so that $u(t,X(t)) = \tfrac{1-X}{1-t}$ for $t\leq X \leq 1$.
- if $u(0,x)=0$, then $X = x$ with $x>1$, i.e. $X>1$.

Finally, for $0\leq t <1$, the solution reads
$$
u(t,x) =
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& 1 &&\text{if}\quad x<t \\
& \tfrac{1-x}{1-t} &&\text{if}\quad t\leq x\leq 1\\
& 0 &&\text{if}\quad x>1 
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2003500/418542) for a book reference (Evans, Ex. 1 p. 139).